# object extend not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax

can somebody help me why in IE function fall to error and not to success as in Chrome or Firefox?

```
var serialized = $form.serializeObject();
if (valid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        data: $.extend(
            {
                productId: {$something}
            },
            serialized
        ),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#summary').html(data.form).show();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            $.message.danger("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `$something`?

Comment: its just an example, in real instead of {$something} is {$uniProductEntity->getProductId()}

Comment: Uh `$uniProductEntity->getProductId()` is php formatted code or the like.  That's not javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe the issue is that you're not using a core jquery method. Its probably not supported by IE or works differently on IE vs chrome/firefox. The core Jquery method that works similar is serializeArray(). See: https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: it's Smarty template, in this is not problem, thank you for your time

Comment: I tried replace serializeArray and now data.form is undefined

Comment: The structure of the data is different when using serializeArray compared to you previous method. Take a look at what serialized contains when you do the new call.
notice that its not an object but an array of objects containing the structure [Name:Value, Name2:Value2]

Comment: data.form generated html code

Comment: In most trouble shooting processes - you want to start with, I'm using {insert frameworks / languages} that's {insert versions} & trying to accomplish {expected output}.

Comment: Thanks for advise, but I am talking about huge project and our company and our system can't get any changes to framework when the project is almost done... Result now - write html before and fill data after